# Stream output of child process in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to stream the output of a child process in Ruby

e.g.

```
p `ping google.com`
```

I want to see the ping responses immediately; I don't want to wait for the process to complete.

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks like a valid, to-the-point question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [IO#popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen):

```
IO.popen("ping -c 3 google.com") do |data|
  while line = data.gets
    puts line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following instead of using backticks:

```
IO.popen('ping google.com') do |io|
  io.each { |s| print s }
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well, Dylan Markow beat me to the punch apparently, but I'll leave this just to show the alternate method of iterating over the results (using `each` versus `while`).

Comment: Don't forget `popen3` if you want to capture `STDERR` as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to capture both the `stdout` and `stderr` you can use `popen2e`:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2e('do something') do |_stdin, stdout_err, _wait_thr|
  stdout_err.each { |line| puts line }
end
```